# Breeze sharp create complexType in blazor to pass some data does not work

Tags: c#, blazor, breeze-sharp

I am using breeze sharp in my C# blazor application to pass data from my server (loaded from EF context (code first objects)) to the client (EntityType objects)
Everything works fine.
Now I want to pass an object with some data from server to client with a class that is not mapped to a database context.
I think I should use ComplexType to pass this data container object so that my client object is inherited from BaseComplexObject
When I try to call my data like I always do:

```
var query = new EntityQuery<T>().InlineCount().From(from);
var response = await entityManager.ExecuteQuery(query, CancellationToken.None);
```

I get an error: A type by this name exists but is not a Breeze.Sharp.EntityType

I don't find any way to pass a custom object with data from server to client.

Comment: _"pass a custom object with data from server to client"_ is dead easy. See WeatherForecast in the sample app.  Your question is hard to understand. Post (an outline of) the class.

Comment: For some reason breeze gives an error that my custom object has no key defined (even when I have a Id property and even added [Key]
ComplexType gives error that it is no EntityType
Where can I find the WeatherForecast sample?

Comment: So it is an EF error? Always post complete error messages. And a stacktrace when available.

Comment: No it is a breeze sharp error.
I tried sending the same object to a normal http call and it arrives fine.
So I don't know why breeze is not happy with it.
An example of passing a custom object in breeze sharp (blazor) would be helpfull